# How to check if i have installed azcopy v10 properly

Tags: azcopy

I have installed azcopy version 10.2.1 on ubuntu 16.04, but if im giving azcopy commend then it is showing command not found. what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with windows.Just added path in environmental variables and it worked fine.